# save_screenshot() Selenium vs PhantomJS

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am using the `save_screenshot(filename)` method and noticed a difference between my Selenium option and the PhantomJS option (with capybara and poltergeist).

Selenium will take a screen shot of the whole page. PhantomJS only captures part of the page, cropping off the bottom.

How do I specify in the PhantomJS driver that I would like the whole page, not just the partial page?

Comment: What do you mean by "selenium driver" and "phantomjs driver"? Selenium is not a browser, but a framework/specification. There is no selenium driver.

Comment: Changed to option, was not sure what to call it.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution.

`save_screenshot(filename,:full => true)`